# MySQL same letter multiple time in a string

Tags: mysql, string

I am looking for a function or some kind of method to check if in a given string a letter appears multiple times (at least 2 times). I am looking for listing all those records which have at least 2 of the same letter in it, for e.g. `Peter` has 2 `e`-s or `Amanda` has 2 `a`-s.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in following way

```
SELECT (LENGTH("adadaaaada") - LENGTH(REPLACE("adadaaaada", 'd', '')));

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| (LENGTH("adadaaaada") - LENGTH(REPLACE("adadaaaada", 'd', ''))) |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                               3 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: replace  "adadaaaada" with your column name and  replace 'd ' with your character

Comment: please try this and let me know

Comment: Actually i don't want to replace any of the letters, i just want to find those elements in the table which have at least 2 from the same letter in it. For e.g. "Peter" has 2 "e"-s or "Amanda" has 2 "a"-s

Comment: :) it is not replacing its getting count don't worry you don't loos any thing

Comment: i have added that replace function to just to get the count but it is not actual replacing it in DB level

Comment: i think you get my point ??

Comment: can this one be modified to check for every letter not only a single one?

Comment: Yeah I got the point but unfortunately i can't use to solve my problem i think :S